# Разработка в Linux

Tags: c#, linux, java, сокет, mysql

Хочу написать простой сервис для линукса, будет сокету выдавать/принимать данные флеш апликухам + mysql.

Есть два вопроса:

1. В какой IDE можно это дело запилить?
2. Как ставить такой процесс на контроль системы в систему, например, через ISPmanager (или еще как)?

Пара пожеланий:

- знаю только есма2, похожие языки C#, Java (C(++) не знаю).
- можно ли это дело разрабатывать под windows так же, ну дебажить там уже и собирать могу под линукс.

Пробовал monodevelop под windows/linux, он компилирует только exe

Comment: Что означает "компилирует только exe"? CLR-сборки обычно имеют расширение `exe` или `dll` независимо от платформы.

Comment: То есть в нативный код monodevelop+c# не компилит никак?

Comment: @ShockWave, а это имеет значение в данном вопросе? Можно собирать CLR-приложение на любой ОС и запускать под .NET/Mono.

Comment: У провайдера нет возможности настроить моно на линукс, я могу только запустить процесс в виде сервиса, пытаюсь сейчас запустить процесс на яве, что то туго.

Answer (score 1):

Вам нужна nodejs. Разрабатывать можно под любой ОС, запускать тоже.
Для старта достаточно посмотреть уроков на javascript.ru

[Исходники](http://nodejs.org/)

[Уроки](http://learn.javascript.ru/nodejs-screencast)

Те цели, которые Вы описали, покрывает полностью.